# Advantages of php gettext over ini resource bundles?

Tags: php, gettext

I've just started using gettext. But, I'm confused, What are the extra advantages of gettext over resource bundles? Just translation, plurals? Even though we need to have seperate files in both scenarios. Please let me know with your valuable suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

gettext supports:

- plurals
- context (e.g. differentiate between "set" the verb and "set" the noun)
- domains (group translations by topic)
- categories (grouping by type like "date related" or "monetary related", tied into the existing locale system)
- a workflow suited for translations (markup, extraction, merging, quality checks) (people regularly underestimate the importance of workflow in i18n)
- a huge ecosystem of tools due to its age

Sooner or later you'll discover your need for each of these things, or at least you'll be surprised how much each of these things improves your i18n work. I'm not entirely sure what you're referring to with "ini resource bundles", but you should make sure all the above are well supported by them.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But, what is domains? In general we dont have any group translations.. right?

Comment: In short, "domains" are the names of the .po files. They simply allow you to group translations.

Comment: Yes. po files are used for key value pairs.. Isn't it? But, where is group translation in this? I'm quite confused. Could you plz explain a bit further?

Comment: You have this source code: `dgettext('admin', 'Some message')` and `dgettext('users', 'Some other message')` the translations of which are in `admin.po` and `users.po` respectively. It's a feature to allow you to group messages by topic.